# Undefined index ONLY when using array

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, undefined

I want to have a SelectAll function which takes in a few arguments (class, table, sort field, and sort order.) The comments explain what is going on (or what is supposed to.)

```
  public static function SelectAll($class, $table, $sort_field, $sort_order = "ASC")
  {

    /* First, the function performs a MySQL query using the provided arguments. */

    $query = "SELECT * FROM " .$table. " ORDER BY " .$sort_field. " " .$sort_order;
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    /* Next, the function dynamically gathers the appropriate number and names of properties. */

    $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);
    for($i=0; $i < ($num_fields); $i++)
    {
      $fetch = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);
      $properties[$i] = "'".$fetch->name."'";
    }
    /*echo [$properties[0]; echo "<br />";}*/
    /* Finally, the function produces and returns an array of constructed objects. */

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    { 
      for($i=0; $i < ($num_fields); $i++)
      {
        $args[$i] = $row[$properties[$i]];
      }
      $array[] = call_user_func_array(new $class, $args);
    } return $array; }
```

Now, the problem I am having is that `$row[$properties[$i]]` results in 'undefined index.'

Right after the function gathers the number/names of the fields and stores them in an array, I can echo the value of `$properties[0]` and it shows as it should, 'id', but `$row[~anything here~]` will simply not work unless I manually enter the value, such as `$row['id']`. As you can imagine very frustrating and confusing.

Why won't this work? Are there any solutions, or alternate ways of accomplishing this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see your `$properties[$i]` array items have **quoted** values like `"'id'"`,
so `$row[$properties[$i]]` <==> `$row["'id'"]` != `$row["id"]`;

And you might want to check `$result === false` after `$result = mysql_query($query);`

Anyway, I think you could replace your function to this (unless you constructed it for demonstration only):

```
public static function SelectAll($class, $method_name, $table, $sort_field, $sort_order = "ASC"){
  /* First, the function performs a MySQL query using the provided arguments. */
  $query = "SELECT * FROM " .$table. " ORDER BY " .$sort_field. " " .$sort_order;
  $result = mysql_query($query);

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    $array[] = call_user_func_array(array($class,'__construct'), $row);

  return $array;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding: when I echo `$properties[0]`, or so on, I get the value of `'id'` back. In this way, `$properties[0]` appears to amount to `'id'`, so `$row[$properties[$0]]` should amount to `$row['id']`. Perhaps you are just seeing the quotations used to surround the string, because it concatenates the two apostrophes around the `$fetch->name`.

Comment: But why are you using the apostrophes, why not just use `$properties[$i] = $fetch->name;` ?

Comment: I see what you mean now. Thank you! That resolved the issue with calling `$row[$properties[$i]]`, although now it appears I have a error from the call_user_func_array: `Object of class Product could not be converted to string`... That's the way it goes, I suppose...

Comment: See the bottom of example 1 of http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php , it might help. Updated the example too.

Comment: Thank you, however what I am trying to do is pass arguments to the __construct method for a dynamically specified class. Also, I think passing along the whole row would dump a lot of information rather than requesting those specific things of it, is that not right?